# How can I pull player names from Rotowire?

Tags: python

I have been using this code below to pull MLB lineups from BaseballPress.com.  However this pulls the official MLB lineups which dont normally get posted until about an hour before the game.

```
 import requests
    import pandas as pd
    import openpyxl
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
    url = "https://www.baseballpress.com/lineups/2022-08-09"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
    
    def get_name(tag):
        if tag.select_one(".desktop-name"):
            return tag.select_one(".desktop-name").get_text()
        elif tag.select_one(".mobile-name"):
            return tag.select_one(".mobile-name").get_text()
        else:
           return tag.get_text()
    
    data = []
    for card in soup.select(".lineup-card"):
        header = [
            c.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
            for c in card.select(".lineup-card-header .c")
        ]
        h_p1, h_p2 = [
            get_name(p) for p in card.select(".lineup-card-header .player")
        ]
        data.append([*header, h_p1, h_p2])
    
        for p1, p2 in zip(
            card.select(".col--min:nth-of-type(1) .player"),
            card.select(".col--min:nth-of-type(2) .player"),
        ):
            p1 = get_name(p1).split(maxsplit=1)[-1]
            p2 = get_name(p2).split(maxsplit=1)[-1]
    
            data.append([*header, p1, p2])
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        data, columns=["Team1", "Date", "Team2", "Player1", "Player2"]
    )
    df.to_excel("MLB Games.xlsx", sheet_name='sheet1', index=False)
    print(df.head(10).to_markdown(index=False))
```

In order to get around this, I found out that Rotowire releases the projected lineups about 24 hours in advance which is what I need for this analysis.  I have changed the python script to match the website, except I am not sure how to alter the `get_name()` tag.  Does anyone know how I would address this portion of the code?  See the new code below:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.rotowire.com/baseball/daily-lineups.php"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

def get_name(tag):
    if tag.select_one(".desktop-name"):
        return tag.select_one(".desktop-name").get_text()
    elif tag.select_one(".mobile-name"):
        return tag.select_one(".mobile-name").get_text()
    else:
       return tag.get_text()

data = []
for card in soup.select(".lineup__main"):
    header = [
        c.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
        for c in card.select(".lineup__teams .c")
    ]
    h_p1, h_p2 = [
        get_name(p) for p in card.select(".lineup__teams .lineup__player")
    ]
    data.append([*header, h_p1, h_p2])

    for p1, p2 in zip(
        card.select(".lineup__list is-visit:nth-of-type(1) .lineup__player"),
        card.select(".lineup__list is-home:nth-of-type(2) .lineup__player"),
    ):
        p1 = get_name(p1).split(maxsplit=1)[-1]
        p2 = get_name(p2).split(maxsplit=1)[-1]

        data.append([*header, p1, p2])

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data, columns=["Team1", "Date", "Team2", "Player1", "Player2"]
)
df.to_excel("MLB Predicted Lineups.xlsx", sheet_name='sheet1', index=False)
print(df.head(10).to_markdown(index=False))
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to look at the actual html to see what tags and attributes the html source is using, in order to correctly identify the content you want. I had made a script to do this, what you are asking here, a while back, so I'm just using/posting that.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd

def get_players(home_away_dict):
    rows = []
    for home_away, v in home_away_dict.items():
        players = v['players']
        print("\n{} - {}".format(v['team'],v['lineupStatus']))
        for idx, player in enumerate(players):
            if home_away == 'Home':
                team = home_away_dict['Home']['team']
                opp = home_away_dict['Away']['team']
            else:
                team = home_away_dict['Away']['team']
                opp = home_away_dict['Home']['team']
            if player.find('span', {'class':'lineup__throws'}):
                playerPosition = 'P'
                handedness = player.find('span', {'class':'lineup__throws'}).text
            else:
                playerPosition = player.find('div', {'class':'lineup__pos'}).text
                handedness = player.find('span', {'class':'lineup__bats'}).text
            
            if 'title' in list(player.find('a').attrs.keys()):
                playerName = player.find('a')['title'].strip()
            else:
                playerName = player.find('a').text.strip()
            
            
            playerRow = {
                'Bat Order':idx,
                'Name':playerName,
                'Position':playerPosition,
                'Team':team,
                'Opponent':opp,
                'Home/Away':home_away,
                'Handedness':handedness,
                'Lineup Status':home_away_dict[home_away]['lineupStatus']}
            
            
            rows.append(playerRow)
            print('{} {}'.format(playerRow['Position'], playerRow['Name']))

    return rows

rows = []
url = 'https://www.rotowire.com/baseball/daily-lineups.php'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
lineupBoxes = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'lineup__box'})

for lineupBox in lineupBoxes:
    try:                    
        awayTeam = lineupBox.find('div', {'class':'lineup__team is-visit'}).text.strip()
        homeTeam = lineupBox.find('div', {'class':'lineup__team is-home'}).text.strip()
        
        print(f'\n\n############\n  {awayTeam} @ {homeTeam}\n############')
    
        awayLineup = lineupBox.find('ul', {'lineup__list is-visit'})
        homeLineup = lineupBox.find('ul', {'lineup__list is-home'})
        
        awayLineupStatus = awayLineup.find('li', {'class':re.compile('lineup__status.*')}).text.strip()
        homeLineupStatus = homeLineup.find('li', {'class':re.compile('lineup__status.*')}).text.strip()
        
        awayPlayers = awayLineup.find_all('li', {'class':re.compile('lineup__player.*')})
        homePlayers = homeLineup.find_all('li', {'class':re.compile('lineup__player.*')})
        
        home_away_dict = {
            'Home':{
                'team':homeTeam, 'players':homePlayers, 'lineupStatus':homeLineupStatus},
            'Away':{
                'team':awayTeam, 'players':awayPlayers,'lineupStatus':awayLineupStatus}}
        
        playerRows = get_players(home_away_dict)
        rows += playerRows
    except:
        continue

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

**Output: First 20 of 300 rows**

```
print(df.head(20).to_markdown(index=False))
|   Bat Order | Name             | Position   | Team   | Opponent   | Home/Away   | Handedness   | Lineup Status   |
|------------:|:-----------------|:-----------|:-------|:-----------|:------------|:-------------|:----------------|
|           0 | Nick Lodolo      | P          | CIN    | PHI        | Home        | L            | Expected Lineup |
|           1 | Jonathan India   | 2B         | CIN    | PHI        | Home        | R            | Expected Lineup |
|           2 | Nick Senzel      | CF         | CIN    | PHI        | Home        | R            | Expected Lineup |
|           3 | Kyle Farmer      | 3B         | CIN    | PHI        | Home        | R            | Expected Lineup |
|           4 | Joey Votto       | 1B         | CIN    | PHI        | Home        | L            | Expected Lineup |
|           5 | Aristides Aquino | DH         | CIN    | PHI        | Home        | R            | Expected Lineup |
|           6 | Albert Almora    | LF         | CIN    | PHI        | Home        | R            | Expected Lineup |
|           7 | Matt Reynolds    | RF         | CIN    | PHI        | Home        | R            | Expected Lineup |
|           8 | Jose Barrero     | SS         | CIN    | PHI        | Home        | R            | Expected Lineup |
|           9 | Austin Romine    | C          | CIN    | PHI        | Home        | R            | Expected Lineup |
|           0 | Ranger Suarez    | P          | PHI    | CIN        | Away        | L            | Expected Lineup |
|           1 | Jean Segura      | 2B         | PHI    | CIN        | Away        | R            | Expected Lineup |
|           2 | Kyle Schwarber   | LF         | PHI    | CIN        | Away        | L            | Expected Lineup |
|           3 | Rhys Hoskins     | 1B         | PHI    | CIN        | Away        | R            | Expected Lineup |
|           4 | J.T. Realmuto    | C          | PHI    | CIN        | Away        | R            | Expected Lineup |
|           5 | Nick Castellanos | RF         | PHI    | CIN        | Away        | R            | Expected Lineup |
|           6 | Alec Bohm        | 3B         | PHI    | CIN        | Away        | R            | Expected Lineup |
|           7 | Darick Hall      | DH         | PHI    | CIN        | Away        | L            | Expected Lineup |
|           8 | Bryson Stott     | SS         | PHI    | CIN        | Away        | L            | Expected Lineup |
|           9 | Matt Vierling    | CF         | PHI    | CIN        | Away        | R            | Expected Lineup |
```

Comment: You are the GOAT. This is exactly what I was looking for and I am trying to figure out how to read the HTMLs but am not great at it yet

Comment: My offer still stands (you should still have me email), if you ever want some help. Feel free to email/whatsapp me whenever.